# How do I get the parent file name from a child file name?

Tags: node.js, path

I am using the following to print the name of the file from a `parent.js` file:

```
let path = require('path');
let fileName = path.basename(__filename);
console.log(fileName);
```

However, I am calling a `child.js` file from the `parent.js` file and I actually want to print the `parent.js`'s file name from the `child.js` file, e.g.

```
console.log(childFileName + " is being called by " + parentFileName);
childFileName is being called by parentFileName
```

Comment: You are doing something like: `const child = require(childFileName)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

**parent.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fileName = path.basename(__filename);
const child = require('child.js')(fileName)
```

**child.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fileName = path.basename(__filename);

module.exports = (requiredFrom = 'Somewhere') => {
    console.log(`${fileName} is being called from ${requiredFrom}`);
}
```

This method requires the child file with the name of the caller as a parameter, which will make it available from the required file as an argument that you can use if `module.exports` returns a function

---

### Edit 1

> I'd prefer to only require path in the child file and print from there or use a different tool

The critical part is passing the necessary information from the parent to the child, and that happens here:

```
const child = require('child.js')(fileName)
```

So, to do the same thing without the need of `path` on the **parent.js** file, you could do the following:

**parent.js**

```
const child = require('child.js')(__filename);
```

**child.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fileName = path.basename(__filename);

module.exports = (fileFrom = '') => {
    const requiredFrom = path.basename(fileFrom) || 'Somewhere';
    console.log(`${fileName} is being called from ${requiredFrom}`);
}
```

**Anyways**, once you require the `path` module anywhere on your app, it will be cached so this won't improve the performance of your app.

---

### Aditionally

You could also do this the *bad* or *hackish* way, it might fit to your needs:

**parent.js**

```
const child = require('child.js');
```

**child.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const fileName = path.basename(__filename);
const requiredFrom = module.parent.filename;

console.log(`${fileName} is being called from ${requiredFrom}`);

delete require.cache[__filename]
```

The drawback of this aproach is that you will lose the ability to retain values accross different requires to the child.js file (this removes the file from `require.cache` every time its required)

Comment: Do you think this is the only way to do it? I'd prefer to only require `path` in the child file and print from there or use a different tool, if `path` is not the best option.

Comment: You could pass only the `__filename` variable if you wish (without doing `path.basename(__filename)` from the parent.js file), the only important step is to pass that info to the required file.

Comment: Thanks, I like using `module.parent.filename`. I also used `path.parse(fullPath).base;` to get just the parent file name alone.